# What is wrong inside my wordpress code

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am adding stylesheet and Javascript files into my plugins. I used wp_enqueue_scripts but files are not getting include inside body.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'channelsScript');
function channelsScript()
{

    wp_enqueue_style('Chanels',plugins_url('JS/style.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style('Chanels',plugins_url('JS/style.min.css'));

    wp_register_script( 'chanelsJS',plugins_url('Chanels/JS/scrip.js'));
    wp_register_script( 'chanelsJS',plugins_url('Chanels/JS/jquery-1.9.1.js'));
    wp_register_script( 'chanelsJS',plugins_url('Chanels/JS/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'));
    wp_register_script( 'chanelsJS',plugins_url('Chanels/JS/jquery-ui.js'));

    wp_enqueue_script("chanelsJS");

    wp_localize_script('chanels','MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')),array('jquery'),null,false);

}
```

I am not sure where is the error when I put all functions body into admin_init hook then style.css /style/min.css include in body but not .js  files.

Comment: I know this may seem kind of obvious but are you 100% sure on the file locations for those first two lines?  I don't know anything about word press but I'm thinking maybe its simply general troubleshooting and not a problem with your hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering several of your scripts with the same name. I'm not exactly sure what the behavior will be when you enqueue `chanelsJS` after reigstering several scripts with that name, but it is definitely not what you want. Also you are registering jquery twice, once minified and once unminified. Try:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'channelsScript');
function channelsScript()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('Chanels',plugins_url('JS/style.min.css'));

    wp_enqueue_script( 'chanelsJS',plugins_url('Chanels/JS/scrip.js'));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'chanelsJS-jquery',plugins_url('Chanels/JS/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'chanelsJS-jquery-ui',plugins_url('Chanels/JS/jquery-ui.js'));


    wp_localize_script('chanelsJS','MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')),array('jquery'),null,false);
}
```

Notice that I just enqueued the scripts immediately instead of registering them first. I also updated the name on your localize script call.

Also, WordPress comes with jQuery and jQuery UI built in. Unless you have a good reason for using your own version of jQuery I would recommend using the WordPress version.

Edit: I just noticed that you're specify the path to one of your scripts as `Chanels/JS/scrip.js`. Is that correct or should it be `Chanels/JS/script.js`?

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply.
    Before I was trying to use Tab feature of jQuery but it was not working using WP jQuery ... When I add manually like above tab worked. After a lot of search of why I red some where that WP does not use full version of jQuery.

   On current code I want to datepicker again it does not worked I tried to add jQuery again ... but now same issue .... I am going to try your expression ... and will reply soon

Comment: wp_enqueue_scripts   still not working while put these script into admin_init it worked .. many many thanks